# How to drag a picturebox control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, events, event-handling

I've got a class called 'MusicNote' which inherits from 'PictureBox'. I'm trying to make it drag vertically when the user clicks on it and moves the mouse up/down.  I've pasted the code below, which works. The problem is that it only works the first time - i.e. the user drags it and it's placed in the new position as it's supposed to. However, when I click it again and drag - it disappears. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is with the MouseUp event handler. In that event you will have to unsubscribe to MouseMove event handler.

```
    public void MusicNote_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        isDragging = false;
        this.MouseMove -= new MouseEventHandler(OnDrag);
    }
```

Multiple subscription to same event is causing your controls top value to be negative.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the currentX  and currentY variables are not updated in OnDrag

```
 public void MusicNote_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            isDragging = false;

            currentX  = e.X;
            currentY  = e.Y;
        }
```

Comment: I tried changing the code as u suggested, the problem now is that when the PictureBox is moved, it constantly vibrates from side to side. What could the problem be?

Comment: updated the answer, so the current values don't case vibrate effect while your moving the item but still updates the values once you have finished moving it.